# How to create labels for each item found in database?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

The problem is like this, I have a announcement table in my database. I want to display the announcement's record that I've found from the database by using labels and text boxes. The question is how do I create new labels and text boxes each time a record is found and i want the layout to be something like this picture.
 [image]

Answer (score 1):

Use a Repeater or a DataList...

Answer (score 1):

Try asp repeater. e.g

```
<asp:Repeater ID="myRepeater" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="myRepeater_ItemDataBound">
   <HeaderTemplate>
   </HeaderTemplate>
   <ItemTemplate> 
        <asp:Label ID="lblHeading" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("TableColoumnName") %>' />
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtHeading" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("TableColoumnName") %>' />
   </ItemTemplate> 
   <FooterTemplate>
   </FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

in code behind provide the data source to your repeater and bind that datasource...

```
protected void myRepeater_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    myRepeater.DataSource = // provide datasource here....
    myRepeater.DataBind(); // bind the data with repeater
}
```

Comment: means every time i found a record i call this method?

Comment: The TableColoumnName is the name of the column in my database?
Can I retrieve all the records and store it in an arraylist first, the display it using those labels?

Answer (score 0):

you can use gridview, repeater etc..

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18132/ASP-NET-using-GridView-Control-as-Lookup